# how can I access state from another slice with redux toolkit

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I have multiple slice and I want to access state from slice in another slice, so how can I access **state** from productsSlice in filterSlice

#### productsSlice

i want to access **products state** from this slice

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
  products: ["data"], // i want to access products in filterSlice 
};

export const productsSlice = createSlice({
  name: "products",
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
});
```

#### filterdSlice

add products state to **filterdProduct**

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
  filteredProduct: [// access products from proudctsSlice ],
}

export const filterSlice = createSlice({
  name : "filter",
  initialState,
  reducers: {  }
})
```

Comment: Use thunk Api https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk second argument thunkAPI will have a method getState to get over-all state.. or pass other state values as payload.. I would recommend you to reorganize your store in a way that all interrelated data are in one slice

Comment: there is a good chance that filtered data shouldn't be part of your store in the first place - that's usually derived data. see https://redux.js.org/recipes/computing-derived-data

Answer (score 2):

Two possible directions for you -

1. Reducers only have access to the state of the slice they are part of and I think you should keep it that way. So may be try redesigning it in a way you won't have to do the state sharing between slices.

Have look at this FAQ question ["how can I share state between reducers?"](https://redux.js.org/faq/reducers#how-do-i-share-state-between-two-reducers-do-i-have-to-use-combinereducers) for more details.

2. And if you still want to go ahead, then you can try importing the store itself in the intended module and do `const reduxStore = store.getState();`. And you access anything you want :)

Comment: 2. will not work - Redux blocks against `getState` calls while a reducer is executed, for good reason.

Comment: I think most sensible solution for this would be to pass the needed information inside action payload while dispatching the action.

e.g. - dispatch(someAction(payloadObj))

where you will stuff the payloadObj with the needed state/data from another slice.